# Some commands not being found after installing Oh-My-Zsh on mac

Tags: terminal, zsh, macos-big-sur, oh-my-zsh

Before installing the Oh-My-Zsh terminal, i had installed node, npm and brew. But after installing Oh-My-Zsh, i get these errors:

```
➜  ~ node
zsh: command not found: node
➜  ~ npm
zsh: command not found: npm
➜  ~ brew
zsh: command not found: brew
➜  ~
```

I searched about it for a while and found that using:

```
source ~/.bash_profile;
```

at the end of the .zshrc file doesn't work, since i don't have a bash_profile file. And uncommenting the following line at the beginning:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

of the .zshrc file doesn't work either. How can fix this?

Comment: @JoanVictor : I don't see why you want to source `.bash_profile` if you don't use a bash login shell. You did not describe **how** you installed zsh, but most likely, you screwed up your `.zshrc` during this process, so this would be the place to start debugging, i.e. running a new zsh using `zsh -ix` and observe what is happening, and where the PATH is modified.

Answer (score 17):

if you look in the .zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh , you find some export for NVM_DIR.

```
  export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && . "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

i solved my pb by adding

```
source $HOME/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh
```

at the end of the .zshrc
and now nvm ( and node -v / ng etc .. ) are working again.

Comment: been searching way too long. thank you

Comment: Brilliant, this is the answer!

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes...

Answer (score -1):

I know that it may be not a proper answer to the question, but i solved the problem uninstalling everything and re-installing everything. Now it works as it should.